# If statement with multiple conditions in Excel and then calculate a formula

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I have an IF statement that says if AG, AL, AJ all have Yes in the cell then I want it to go to a lookup table to retrieve a result.  I then want it to take that result and perform a calculation but I don't know how to write it.

If one of the three cells has a no in it, then I just want it to return the value in cell AK

Here is an example:

```
IF(AG="Yes", AI="Yes", AJ="Yes"), VLOOKUP(Payout Table!A:B,201, 2,True), (O7*H17*AK) False=AK
```

This is my first time trying to do this so if you can recommend a link I can go to too better understand the correct formula that would be great.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do with your psuedo-formula. Can you write it, in words, exactly what you are trying to accomplish. The first part is good "If AG, Al and AJ all have Yes, then lookup.. " and it gets muddy. What value are you looking up? Into what range/table? Which value from that table are trying to extract? What calculation are you wanting to perform on that extracted value?

Comment: I am trying to determine if someone qualifies for an accelerator and if yes then I would take my attainment % (K24) go to the lookup table and find the accelerated % then take their monthly target (O7) * their performance measure (H17) * the new attainment based on the table (AK24).  If they did not get a yes in all 3 cells (lets say AG24, AI24 and AJ24, I just want it to look at their original attainment in K24 (because they did not meet the criteria for an accelerator).

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is the AND function. AND returns TRUE if all of its own arguments are TRUE. ie:

```
=IF(AND(AG1="Yes", AI1="Yes", AJ1="Yes"), VLOOKUP(Payout Table!A:B,201, 2,True)*(O7*H17*AK), AK1)
```

Note also that I have fixed your formula for making the VLOOKUP amount multiply against your other cells, and also that I have added row references to what you had there ("AG" is not a valid cell reference; replace "AG1" with the appropriate row number you want to check against).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AND as well as change the order of your VLOOKUP like below:

```
=IF(AND(AG="Yes",AI="Yes",AJ="Yes"),VLOOKUP(201,Payout Table!A:B, 2,True)*(O7*H17*AK), AK1)
```